# Wrap Text on Same Line as Checkbox

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm having some trouble with some displays on the responsive version of my bootstrap application. What is the best way to get the text to sit inline with the checkboxes (and wrapping around underneath)?

The line in question is the following:

```
/* Please ignore my use of &nbsp;... i've changed that to a margin in the latest revision */
<li class='list-group-item'><input type='checkbox' id='checkbox".$i.$iter."' name='pagesToGenerate[]' value='".$file."'/>&nbsp;&nbsp;<label class='files' for='checkbox".$i.$iter."'>".str_replace($dir, '', $t)."</label></li>
```

[Here's a picture of my issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vK1m7.png)

```
<div class="panel-group">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <h4 class="panel-title">
                <a data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapse<?php echo $i ?>"><?php echo basename($dir)?></a>
            </h4>
        </div>
        <div id="collapse<?php echo $i ?>" class="panel-collapse collapse">
            <ul class="list-group">
                <?php
                    $dir = "templates/".$dirname."/";

                    $remaining = array_diff(glob($dir.'*.docx'), glob($dir.'~$*'));
                    $iter = 0;

                    echo "<ul class='list-group filesChecklist'>";
                    foreach ($remaining as $t) {
                        // '$i.$iter' is to differentiate the labels for each group
                        $file = implode(':',[$dirname, str_replace($dir, '', $t)]);
                        echo "<li class='list-group-item'><input type='checkbox' id='checkbox".$i.$iter."' name='pagesToGenerate[]' value='".$file."'/>&nbsp;&nbsp;<label class='files' for='checkbox".$i.$iter."'>".str_replace($dir, '', $t)."</label></li>";
                        $iter++;
                    }
                    echo "</ul>";
                ?>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Hopefully that makes sense. Help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

The quick and dirty way would be to use float.

```
.list-group-item input {
    float: left;
}
```